# Continuesly increase count while $.post() fetch data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got a $.post() request.

```
var count = 0;
function price(){
   $.post('price/new.php',
   { item:val },
   function(value){
       //do
   })
};
```

Once the `price()` is called, how do I do a count++ every ½ a second?

I did the below but

```
function price(){
   trackC = setInterval(function() {
     count++;
     if(count==16){
        //clearInterval func
     }
   },500);
   $.post('price/new.php',
   { item:val },
   function(value){
       //do
   })
};
```

But the `count++` won't get called immediately when `price()` is triggered. It starts doing the `count++` after the `value` is returned from the server.

How do I start `count++` immediately when the `price()` function is called and do the `count++` every half a second?

Comment: `It starts doing the count++ after the value is returned` is not correct. The interval starts immediately, but it initially fires only after 500ms, when the callback has probably already been called. So it "looks like" it only counts after the callback. Follow @Bartek Gladys instructions and it will count before the callback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
function price(){
   count++;
   trackC = setInterval(function() {
     count++;
     if(count==16){
        //clearInterval func
     }
   },500);
   $.post('price/new.php',
   { item:val },
   function(value){
       //do
   })
};
```